# asp.net webfarm deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-farm

Can somebody point me to a resource where I can details on considerations for deploying asp.net application in web farm scenarios ?

Is web farm deployment a consideration when during low level design ?

Answer (score 0):

Web Farm deployment is surely a consideration during low level design. You would need to take decision on where to store your session variables which largely depends on how you are doing your request distribution.

Browse through this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/gopenath/page107182007032219am/page1.aspx) and see if it answers all your queries.